# How to display specific element of last row of parsed CSV data, JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, csv, parsing

I'm working on a dashboard in-browser app... I'm using Papa Parse to parse a client-provided CSV.

The parsing is working, and I'm using a callback to log data out in console.

Quite simply, I need to store the the 10th position of the final 2 rows (number of rows subject to change) in 2 separate JS vars to then display in the HTML.

All, help is appreciated!

Current Code:

```
function showData(data) {
  console.log(data);
  console.log(data.item);
}

function parseData(url, callBack) {
  Papa.parse(url, {
    download: true,
    dynamicTyping: true,
    complete: function(results) {
        callBack(results.data);
    }
  });
}
```

These are the array results:

```
22205: (105) ["c:\Users\admin\Documents\IxChariot\Tests\8ss_hk_test_udp.tst", "4ss", 4215, 4215, 17337500000, null, 3067971000, 14269529000, 82.304, 204.118, 0.385, 1946.667, null, null, null, null, null, null, 11875000, null, null, null, 9773650, null, null, 2101350, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, …]
22206: (105) ["c:\Users\admin\Documents\IxChariot\Tests\8ss_hk_test_udp.tst", "8ss", 17922, 17922, 18512800000, null, 13073661980, 5439138020, 29.38, 869.816, 0.394, 696.907, null, null, null, null, null, null, 12680000, null, null, null, 3725437, null, null, 8954563, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, …]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your callback method, surely you just need to pull out the tenth item from each array?

```
function callback:(data) {
    return {
        first: data[data.length - 2][9],
        second: data[data.length - 1][9],
    }
}
```

Then when you want to assign your variables you can do something like:

```
const { first: variableOne, second: variableTwo } = callback(data)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The destructuring should be `const { first: variableOne, second: variableTwo } = `

Comment: Edited accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar - it’s been a long day in the office.

Comment: Thank you both. This looks like the right approach. Marcus, I don't see how your callback function fits into my code exactly. As a stand alone function, it's throwing an error because of the ":" syntax. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: You mean the object returned from callback? You could simply do const results = callback(data) and then reference results.first, results.second instead. As I haven’t seen the wider context it’s hard to be too prescriptive, but you should get the jist.